# Сериализация моделей в связке 1 ко многим PYTHON + FLASK + SQL_ALCHEMY + MARSHMALLO

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть две модели:

```
class Categories(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "categories"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    main_name = db.Column(db.String(255))


class Products(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "products"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    date_create = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    categoryid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    img = db.Column(db.String(255))
    authorid = db.Column(db.Integer )
    category = db.relationship('Categories', backref=backref("products"))
```

К ним две схемы MARSHMALLO :

```
class CategoriesSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
class Meta:
    model = Categories
    fields= ('id', 'name', 'main_name')



categories_schema = CategoriesSchema()
categories_schema = CategoriesSchema(many=True)


class ProductsSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields= ('id', 'name', 'description', 'date_create', 'categoryid', 'img', 'authorid', 'category')
    category = ma.Nested(CategoriesSchema)


products_schema = ProductsSchema()
products_schema = ProductsSchema(many=True)
```

Получаю данный обычным SQL_Alchemy:

```
def get_all_products():
    products = Products.query.all()
    result = products_schema.dump(products)
    return jsonify(result.data)
```

На выходе такой вот ответ JSON:

```
[
{
    "authorid": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "categoryid": 1,
    "date_create": "2019-07-30T08:15:32.876095+00:00",
    "description": "Очень хороший холодильник, для вас и вашей семьи!",
    "id": 1,
    "img": "Холодильник VEKO.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ",
    "name": "Холодильник VEKO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "
},
{
    "authorid": 1,
    "category": 4,
    "categoryid": 4,
    "date_create": "2019-07-30T08:16:36.082716+00:00",
    "description": "Очень хороший пылесос! Берите плес для вас и вашей семьи!",
    "id": 2,
    "img": "RED-DED MACHINE.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ",
    "name": "RED-DED MACHINE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "
}
]
```

Подскажите, пожст
Как сделать, что б category в ответе была не просто id, а объект типа Categories?